# My form resets but not the styles,

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, styles

When i close the modal the form inside resets but not the styles, if the password don't match it gets a red border color and if i close it remains the same?

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function checkForm(){
var nameRg = document.getElementById("nameRg").value;
var ok = true;
if (nameRg == "") {document.get.ElementById("nameRg").style.borderColor="#ff2020";
  ok = false;}
 return ok;
};
 $(.modal).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
$(this).find('form')[0].reset();
 });
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="post" onsubmit="return checkForm()"> 
    <div class="form-group register-group register-name-group"> 
    <label for="name">Name :</label> 
    <input id="nameRg" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="eg. Leutrim Osmani"> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

Comment: do you mean `document.getElementById("nameRg")` instead of `document.get.ElementById("nameRg")`? Can you show us your HTML?

Comment: Yes, this website generated the dots automatically :S

Comment: [link](http://prntscr.com/7uwtp7)

Comment: @LeutrimOsmani Please post the HTML in your original post, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reset()` method only resets the input values of the form. You will have to manually reset the styles. So in your modal close event function, you will have to have a line like this to reset the border color back to your default:

```
document.getElementById("nameRg").style.borderColor = "#ff2020";
```